# MVVM: Notifying property change in the UI

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding, inotifypropertychanged

I am building a logger. The UI(LoggerView) binds to three properties of LogItem: the `DateTime`, `Status`, and the `Message`. When I run the program, the logging events do get created and logged into the UI properly. However, when I close the UI, log more additional events, and open the UI once more, the additional events do get logged into `events` but they do not appear in the UI.

The problem is that the UI is not being notified when new `LogItems` are being added to the collection. How can I notify the UI when additional `LogItems` is being added?

LoggerViewModel:

```
[Export]
[PartCreationPolicy(System.ComponentModel.Composition.CreationPolicy.Shared)]
public class LoggerViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    protected static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(LoggerViewModel));
    private Hierarchy h = LogManager.GetRepository() as Hierarchy;

    [ImportingConstructor]
    public LoggerViewModel()
    {
        LogItems = new ObservableCollection<LogItem>();
        foreach (var customLog in CustomLogger.GetLogItems())
        {
            var logItem = new LogItem(customLog.TimeStamp, customLog.Status, customLog.Message);
            LogItems.Add(logItem);
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<LogItem> _logItems;
    public ObservableCollection<LogItem> LogItems
    {
        get { return _logItems; }
        set { _logItems = value; }
    }

    private DateTime _timeStamp;
    public DateTime TimeStamp
    {
        get { return _timeStamp; }
        set
        {
            if (value == _timeStamp)
                return;
            _timeStamp = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("TimeStamp");
        }
    }

    private Level _status;
    public Level Status
    {
        get { return _status; }
        set
        {
            if (value == _status)
                return;
            _status = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Status");
        }
    }

    private string _message;
    public string Message
    {
        get { return _message; }
        set
        {
            if (value == _message)
                return;
            _message = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Message");
        }
    }
}
```

LoggerView XAML:

```
    <ListView Grid.Row="1" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" VerticalContentAlignment="Bottom" ItemsSource="{Binding LogItems}">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Width="150" Header="Date And Time" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=DataContext.TimeStamp, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}}">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow" TextAlignment="Center"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Width="50" Header="Status" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=DataContext.Status, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}}">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow" TextAlignment="Center"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Width="1800" Header="Message">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow" Text="{Binding Path=DataContext.Message, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

LoggerView Logic:

```
[Export]
[PartCreationPolicy(System.ComponentModel.Composition.CreationPolicy.NonShared)]
public partial class LoggerView : Window
{
    private LoggerViewModel _viewModel;
    protected static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(LoggerView));
    private Hierarchy h = LogManager.GetRepository() as Hierarchy;

    [ImportingConstructor]
    public LoggerView(LoggerViewModel viewModel)
    {
        _viewModel = viewModel;
        this.DataContext = _viewModel;
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

CustomLogger: `LogItems` is being created from `events`

```
public class CustomLogger
{
    protected static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(CustomLogger));
    static MemoryAppender memoryAppender = new MemoryAppender();
    private Hierarchy h = LogManager.GetRepository() as Hierarchy;

    public CustomLogger()
    {
        log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure(new System.IO.FileInfo(@"C:\Users\username\Documents\GitHub\MassSpecStudio\MassSpecStudio 2.0\source\MassSpecStudio\Core\app.config"));
        memoryAppender = h.Root.GetAppender("MemoryAppender") as MemoryAppender;
    }

    public static ObservableCollection<LogItem> GetLogItems()
    {
        var events = memoryAppender.GetEvents();
        ObservableCollection<LogItem> LogItems = new ObservableCollection<LogItem>();
        foreach (LoggingEvent loggingEvent in events)
        {
            DateTime TimeStamp = loggingEvent.TimeStamp;
            Level Status = loggingEvent.Level;
            string Message = loggingEvent.RenderedMessage;

            LogItems.Add(new LogItem(TimeStamp, Status, Message));
        }
        return LogItems;
    }
}
```

LogItem:

```
    public class LogItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        private DateTime _datetime;
        private Level _status;
        private string _message;

        public LogItem(DateTime datetime, Level status, string message)
        {
            this._datetime = datetime;
            this._status = status;
            this._message = message;
        }

        public enum LogLevel
        {
            Debug = 0,
            Info = 1,
            Warn = 2,
            Error = 3,
            Fatal = 4,
        }

        public DateTime TimeStamp
        {
            get
            {
                return _datetime;
            }
            set
            {
                if (_datetime != value)
                {
                    _datetime = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged("DateTime");
                }
            }
        }

        public Level Status
        {
            get
            {
                return _status;
            }
            set
            {
                if (_status != value)
                {
                    _status = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged("Status");
                }
            }
        }

        public string Message
        {
            get
            {
                return _message;
            }
            set
            {
                if (_message != value)
                {
                    _message = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged("Error");
                }
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void RaisePropertyChanged(string info)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null) { PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info)); }
        }
    }
```

LoggerMenuItem:

```
[Export]
public partial class LoggerMenuItem : MenuItem
{
    protected static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(LoggerMenuItem));
    private readonly IServiceLocator _serviceLocator;

    [ImportingConstructor]
    public LoggerMenuItem(IServiceLocator serviceLocator)
    {
        _serviceLocator = serviceLocator;
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void MenuItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        LoggerView window = _serviceLocator.GetInstance<LoggerView>();
        window.Owner = Application.Current.MainWindow;
        window.Show();
    }
}
```

UPDATE:

I noticed that my static method `GetLogItems()` from CustomLogger is only execute when the UI is opened during the first time. `GetLogItems()` does not execute after when the `events` get updated.

Is there a way to notify property change in the events?

To solve this problem, I think it will be best to get the setters for LogItems, DateTime, Status, and Message to fire whenever the UI is being fired. The `MenuItem_Click` method is responsible for firing the UI. Is it possible to call `NotifyPropertyChanged` right before `window.Show()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are replacing the LogItems ObservableCollection after the binding has been resolved and you are not calling NotifyPropertyChanged to inform the UI.

Try changing the LogItems property to call NotifyPropertyChanged:

```
private ObservableCollection<LogItem> _logItems;
public ObservableCollection<LogItem> LogItems
{
    get { return _logItems; }
    set
    {
        _logItems = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("LogItems");
    }
}
```

I think you need to change the columns like this:

```
<GridView>
    <GridViewColumn Width="150" Header="Date And Time" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding TimeStamp}">
        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow" TextAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn>
    <GridViewColumn Width="50" Header="Status" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Status}">
        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow" TextAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn>
    <GridViewColumn Width="1800" Header="Message" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Message}">
        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow" Text="{Binding}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn>
</GridView>
```

Comment: So does the GetItems method need to be called to get new log items, and so there aren't any new items being added to the collection?

Comment: Yes, `GetLogItems()` method need to be called whenever something gets logged. Since if new events get added to events, this mean that something is logged. In this case, the `GetLogItems()` should be called.

Another problem is that in my design, the UI is binded with `DateTime`, `Status`, and `Message`, which means that nothing is currently displayed in the UI because all the logger information is in the object `LogItems`.

Comment: You will need to ensure that the method is called when a new Item is logged, but it does not seem ideal as it will get every log message every time a new message is added. Could do with some extensive refactoring.